# Configure error for ffmpeg 6.1 when executing in bash 5.0.17

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, configure

I am trying to install ffmpeg 6.1 (https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-6.1.1.tar.xz), but when executing the configure script my bash version 5.0.17 removes the double quotes from the parameters containing the condition to select the version of the libraries being searched for to pass this parameter to pkg-config.

For example, when processing code

```
check_pkg_config libopenjpeg "libopenjp2 >= 2.1.0" openjpeg.h opj_version
```

, the pkg-config call will look something like

```
pkg-config --exists libopenjp2 >= 2.1.0
```

As a result, configure execution stops with the following error.

```
ERROR: libopenjp2 >= 2.1.0 not found using pkg-config
```

As a hint, you may be prompted to set the path to the 2.1.0.pc file in PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

It is interesting that this is the case in other versions of bash, for example, this problem is not observed in version 5.1.16.

Does this mean that bash version 5.0.17 will actually not be able to work with configure to build most code sources, because such version selection conditions are used quite often when searching for the right libraries?

Or perhaps I can influence this bash behaviour in some way? Or, alternatively, have I misinterpreted the problem at all and the solution is in a completely different area?

The problem was identified in the Linux Mint 20.1 distribution.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20.1
Release:    20.1
Codename:   ulyssa
```

First of all, I checked that if I call pkg-config correctly, it can find the right library on my system.

```
$ pkg-config --exists "libopenjp2 >= 2.1.0"
$ echo $?
0
```

or

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs "libopenjp2 >= 2.1.0"
-I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.3 -lopenjp2
```

Next, I examined the configure code associated with this problem and came to the conclusion I outlined above.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with bash 5.0.17. `pkg-config --exists libopenjp2 \>= 2.1.0` should work equally fine too, so the issue is not quote removal.

Comment: Unfortunately, when bash removes the double quotes when executing the configure script, it does not add a backslash character. For example: 

```$ pkg-config --libs libopenjp2 \>= 2.1.0
-lopenjp2

but

$ pkg-config --libs libopenjp2 >= 2.1.0
Package 2.1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `2.1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package '2.1.0' found```

Comment: The backslash is irrelevant here, `pkg-config --exists libopenjp2 \>= 2.1.0` and `e='libopenjp2 >= 2.1.0'; pkg-config --exists $e` do the same thing. The problem is something else, but you need to give us more details; like the exact steps to reproduce the error, the full error message, how exactly you tested different versions of bash etc.

Comment: So the problem is that bash works in such a way that pkg-config doesn't get any of the case with the correct options.   Instead, it gets a variant with no quotes and no backslash. So pkg-config can't find the specified library.  We get the variant ```pkg-config exists libopenjp2 >= 2.1.0```.

Comment: In other words, if you use casess ```pkg-config --exists libopenjp2 \>= 2.1.0``` or ```pkg-config --exists "libopenjp2 >= 2.1.0"``` then pkg-config works correctly.

Comment: The issue is not with pkg-config, but with bash 5.0.17, which does not properly handle double quotes when executing the configure script.

Comment: But it works fine with bash 5.0.17 here on my computer. I don't get the `Package 2.1.0 was not found` error.